# Weblogic Ant JWSC task to generate a webservice war file

Tags: java, ant, build, weblogic, java-web-start

I am running a jwsc ant task to generate a war file. It is working fine for me if I add the weblogic.jar to classpath before running the ant script (CLASSPATH=/opt/bea/weblogic91/server/lib/weblogic.jar export CLASSPATH)

But is is not working if I add this in my build.xml as follows:

```
<target name="GenerateWarFiles">   
<path id="lib.jwsc.id">  
<pathelement path="/opt/bea/weblogic91/server/lib/weblogic.jar"/>  
</path>  
<taskdef name="jwsc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask" classpathref="lib.jwsc.id"/>  
<jwsc srcdir="${src.java.dir}" destdir="${build.war.file.dir}" verbose="on" debug="on" classpathref="lib.jwsc.id">  
<jws file="sep/com/bt/prf/jws/TypeImpl.java" compiledWsdl="${ivy.lib.dir}/WSDLC/Jwslib-8.0.jar" />  
</jwsc>   
</target>
```

I am getting the following error.

```
[AntUtil.deleteDir] Deleting directory /var/tmp/_927vxb

BUILD FAILED
/wls_domains/CIT/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/util/Ivy/build.xml:231: Deployment descriptor: /var/tmp/_927vxb/web.xml does not exist.
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:184)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: Deployment descriptor: /var/tmp/_927vxb/web.xml does not exist.
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.War.setWebxml(War.java:95)
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.jar(JwscTask.java:397)
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.pkg(JwscTask.java:331)
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:166)
... 17 more
--- Nested Exception ---
Deployment descriptor: /var/tmp/_927vxb/web.xml does not exist.
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.War.setWebxml(War.java:95)
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.jar(JwscTask.java:397)
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.pkg(JwscTask.java:331)
at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:166)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)

Total time: 1 minute 3 seconds
```

I am running weblogic91 in Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that in your deployment target (Which isn't posted here) is trying to 'clean' up the deployment directory, and is failing when it can't find the file called `/var/tmp/_927vxb/web.xml`

3 suggestions:

1. Run `touch /var/tmp/_927vxb/web.xml` from the command line and try to run the build/deployment again. This will create an empty file that will at least let you get past the file not found on delete error. This is not a long term solution, but rather an attempt to expose the real issue.
2. Look at line 231 in your `/wls_domains/CIT/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/util/Ivy/build.xml` file. Perhaps there is a `delete` ant task that is `failing on error`. If this is the case, add `failonerror="false" to the ant task that is causing the issue.
3. Post more of your build file here. Being able to align the line numbers in the file with the error will help in decoding the issue.

Comment: Hii,
I tried by running the 1 st and 2 nd suggestions. Build is successful but the war file is not generated. I am pasting the last three lines of the build out put
[AntUtil.deleteDir] Deleting directory /var/tmp/_927vxb0
     [jwsc] JWS Compile failed: Deployment descriptor: /var/tmp/_927vxb0/web.xml does not exist.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 2 seconds


here is my build.xml. only one task is failing remaining all tasks are passsing.

Comment: Looks like I'll need you to do suggestion 3 to go any farther with this. The stack trace helps, but without more of the build file to loof at, it's kind of a black box to me. Whatever you do, good luck